# Allow the insert of Custom Records even if some of them fail as duplicates

Tags: dml, duplicate-management, saveresult, allornone

I want to ignore a bunch of records (Custom settings in fact) and want the transaction to ignore Duplicate errors. All other errors should make the insert fail. If a duplicate exists simply skip the insert.

This is [how I try to solve this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194642). If there is an alternative it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you prepare your data upfront by looking at whatever the unique key happens to be? Stick existing data into `Map<String, CustomSetting__c>`, then loop through the items you want to insert and compare? Less attempted DMLs (and rows wasted), less pain with rollbacks if needed...

For **List** custom settings you should only need the `getAll()` method, something like this:

```
Map<String, CustomSetting__c> m = CustomSetting__c.getAll();
List<CustomSetting__c> toInsert = new List<CustomSetting__c>();

for(CustomSetting__c c : scope){
    if(m.containsKey(c.Name)){
        continue;
    }
    m.put(c.Name, c);
    toInsert.add(c);
}

insert toInsert;
```

(might be smart to sprinkle some `String.toLower()` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` around because with `Strings` as map keys the case matters).

For **hierarchy** custom settings it's bit more annoying as there's no "getAll" approach. You could carefully do the matching by looking at what's the type of `SetupOwnerId`, call `getOrgDefaults()` if it's equal to `UserInfo.getOrganizationId()`, else call `getValue()`... But I'd be tempted to just query them all (if there aren't too many rows)

```
Map<Id, CustomSetting__c> m = new Map<Id, CustomSetting__c>();
for(CustomSetting__c c : [SELECT SetupOwnerId, Name FROM CustomSetting__c]){
    m.put(c.SetupOwnerId, c);
}
```

and then proceed as with list settings.

Another idea for hierarchy settings:

1. generate `Set<Id>` containing `SetupOwnerId`s of data you're about to insert
2. `SELECT SetupOwnerId FROM CustomSetting__c WHERE Id IN :myIds`, throw it into a Map where key is also `SetupOwnerId`
3. Do some magic with Maps, their (key)Sets,`containsKey()` or `Set.remove()` methods.